# How to get a character from a number in Java

Tags: java, character

Hi I want the opposite function of getNumericValue

```
int i = Character.getNumericValue('A');
if('A' == Character.someFunction(i)){
      System.out.println("hooray");
}
```

I have tried "Character.forDigit" but this seems to be completely wrong.

Am new to java so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite is [`Character.forDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit(int,%20int))

```
if(Character.forDigit(Character.getNumericValue('b'), Character.MAX_RADIX) == 'b') {
    // true!
}
if(Character.forDigit(Character.getNumericValue('B'), Character.MAX_RADIX) == 'b') {
    // true!
}


if(Character.getNumericValue('B') == Character.getNumericValue('b')) {
    // true!
}
if((int)('B') == (int)'b') {
    // false
}
```

Although given your question I think your looking for the actual ASCII char code for the letter.

Read this [Java Character literals value with getNumericValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717898/java-character-literals-value-with-getnumericvalue) post to see more information about `Character.getNumericValue`

Answer (score 2):

To convert between `char` and `int` you can use typecasting. For example:

```
char myChar = (char) 65;
System.out.println(myChar);
```

will result in `A`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Character.getNumericValue('A') convert 'A' into unicode representation of the char. Probably you don't want to use that.

> The letters A-Z in their uppercase ('\u0041' through '\u005A'),
>   lowercase ('\u0061' through '\u007A'), and full width variant
>   ('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A') forms have
>   numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode
>   specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char
>   values.